# How to change 2 images simultaneously upon each click in android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void fade(View view) {

        ImageView homerImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homerImageView);
        ImageView bartImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bartImageView) ;

        bartImageView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(5000);

        homerImageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(5000);

        for ()


    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

In my app have totally  2 images upon click one fade out to 0 alpha and second comes back from 0 alpha to 1 alpha when I run the  app and click on the image change to other but the only thing I want that it keeps doing that upon each click on the image like if I click on image 1 it changes to image 2 but upon clicking on image to it do not change to image 1 any solution very simple will be helpfull thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of applying fade here, if you want to hide 1 image and show another and vise-versa?

Comment: i want that one image get disappear slowly and other come slowly to give more graphic thats why i chose fade

Comment: You can use Handler to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this.** Just a **hint** may not suits what exactly you want

In your image onClick method:

```
switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.id_one:
                imgOne.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(5000);
                callHandler(imgTwo);
                break;
            case R.id.id_two:
                imgTwo.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(5000);
                callHandler(imgOne);
                break;
        }
```

`Handler` function is like,

```
private void callHandler(final ImageView imgView) {
        new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                imgOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgView.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(5000);
            }
        },5000);
    }
```

Comment: so difficult method you are giving just to change the image from 1 to 2 upon each click like 1 to 2 then 2 to 1 just image keep switching upon touching it

Comment: this is not required for simple switch over on a onClick, this is because of fade style.